# How to use printf to output two links?

Tags: plugins, php

I want to use `printf` to print this:

> Login or register to be able to add new adverts

I need to print two links, one for login and one for registration. i know how to print one but i don't know how i can add second in the same text.

Please if somebody knows, help me :D

```
apply_filters("adverts_action_$action", $content, $form);
    function wpjb_check_user_logged_in() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
       ( 'Non-Personalized Message!' );
    } else {

         $text = __('<strong><a href="%2$s">login</a> or <a href="%2$s">register</a>register to be able to add new adverts</strong>', 'adverts');
        printf( '<div>'.$text.'</div>', wp_get_current_user(), wp_login_url());
    }
}
add_action( 'adverts_action', 'wpjb_check_user_logged_in' );
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$text = __( '<strong><a href="%1$s">login</a> or <a href="%2$s">register</a> to be able to add new adverts</strong>', 'adverts' );
printf( '<div>' . $text . '</div>', wp_login_url(), wp_registration_url());
```

Comment: Thanks! And how it will look if i want use "sprintf" ?

Comment: @Proctosone sprintf is the same as printf, but it does not print the string, just returns it, so you need echo too in order to print it